# How to deploy the contents of container build by docker-compose after all containers are ready to remote server?

Tags: shell, docker, jenkins, docker-compose, continuous-integration

I have a fine working docker-compose for my local environment to work and play around with. the docker compose will add my website, mysql, and some other things in order to make everything work.

All the necessary files are now in one of my docker containers, and i can

```
docker cp container_name:/var/www/html/. dist/
```

to have my files on my local machine in the dist directory, where I am able to transfer the files to my server.

The next step is to automate the whole process, for what i want to use Jenkins.

Its not the first time that I use Jenkins, but for some reason I cannot get this to work.

I checkout my project from SCM into Jenkins, and be able to run docker-compose up --build, but when i dont use the -d parameter it will become stuck in this command line, since docker-compose up --build will only terminate with CTRL+C, therefore I use the -d parameter.

Afterwards i use

```
docker cp container_name:/var/www/html/. dist/
```

to move the files into my Jenkins directory, but here lies the next problem: Since I use the -d parameter the docker cp command does not wait for the docker-compose up --build to be completely finished.

So I tried to use something like

```
docker-compose logs -f -t | sed '/^Almost ! Starting web server now$/ q'
```

after the build command to determine a point in the build process where I am confident that all the files and installations made by custom docker_run.sh etc. files are already executed.

But it doesn't work. Either the job never ends and gets stuck or my command doesn't exactly wait for the "Almost ! Starting web server now" line in the docker-compose logs and will directly copy the files without the docker_run.sh having done its modifications inside of the container.

This is my current jenkins shell script inside the deployment job for my project.

```
# Create a dist directory
mkdir dist

# Build Docker
docker-compose up -d --build

# Wait for the logs to output "Almost ! Starting web server now"
docker-compose logs -f -t | sed '/^Almost ! Starting web server now$/ q'

# Copy files from container to jenkins directory "dist"
docker cp container_name:/var/www/html/. dist/

# Stop the containers, as I dont need them anymore
docker-compose down

# Go into the dist folder
cd dist

# Send files to remote
rsync -aHAXx --numeric-ids -e "some_parameters_here" . ssh_user@ssh_ip:httpdocs
```

I expect docker-compose to start by jenkins and that jenkins waits until it is ready, then cp the files to jenkins directory, then sends to remote server.

Actual result, as stated above, is either a never ending job of Jenkins, or Jenkins sending the files from docker without docker being 100% built.

Comment: mybe your regex in sed is wrong, could you copy the hole line from the logs

Comment: When I connect to the jenkins Server via cli, the SED-process works properly. Actually i forgot to mention whether or not this is even the correct way of archieving what i want to do..

Comment: You might be able to use healthchecks and "depends on" in your docker-compose to let docker automatically configure the wait times. I've also used init scripts inside the containers themselves to check for required remote services, like a postgres instance before completing their own startup.

Comment: As a side point, we have jenkins check out the images from a private repo and build them locally using a groovy pipeline. This has proven to be very robust for us.

Comment: Hi @Dov Rine,
I do the healthchecks and depends on stuff in the yml file. The thing is that the docker-compose never ends by it self as it ends in an apache server listening to localhost. To your side point, what do you mean by "build them locally"? Inside Jenkins? Or where? And how did you configure your groovy pipeline? I am highly interested!

Comment: Yes. Inside the jenkins pipeline. I'll post a sample in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an excerpt of one of our groovy based pipeline build steps with the sensitive bits replaced. This pipeline actually has 14 containers in it:

Under pipeline --> configure, select either pipeline script or pipeline from scm.

pipeline.groovy

```
pipeline {
  environment {
    registry = "fqdn.to.our.private.docker.repo"
  }
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Cloning Git') {
        steps {
            git(    
                branch: 'develop',
                credentialsId: 'jenkins-user-ssh-key-credentials-id',
                url: 'jenkinsuser@git_repo_server:/path/to/project/repo'
            )
        }
    }
    stage('Building Container1 image') {
      steps{
        script {
          container1Image = docker.build(registry + "/container1_name:tag", "-f path/to/dockerfile/for/this/container/Dockerfile ./docker/build/context/in/the/checked/out/repo/for/this/container")
        }
      }
    }
    stage('Deploy Container1 Image to Docker Repository') {
        steps {
            script {
            docker.withRegistry('https://fqdn.to.our.private.docker.repo', 'jenkins-credentials-to-access-the-docker-repo') {
                    container1Image.push()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    stage('Building Container2 image') {
      steps{
        script {
          container2Image = docker.build(registry + "/container2_name:tag", "-f path/to/dockerfile/for/this/container/Dockerfile ./docker/build/context/in/the/checked/out/repo/for/this/container")
        }
      }
    }
    stage('Deploy Container2 Image to Docker Repository') {
        steps {
            script {
            docker.withRegistry('https://fqdn.to.our.private.docker.repo', 'jenkins-credentials-to-access-the-docker-repo') {
                    container2Image.push()
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```